# how to embed an flv or swf in html with player?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, embed, flv

so im learning html and css through a book i purchased that is some what out dated (at least i think due to some of the inactive resources that are offered to use in the book) so far im learning some good information from it, except for one section. The section " Preparing a Flash video for your site" and "adding a flash video to your page" while using a player from www.osplayer.com (no longer in use since 2014) and the code involves...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {};
    var params = {movie: "../video/puppy.flv"};
    swfobject.embedSWF("flash/osplayer.swf", "snow", "400", "320", "8.0.0", flashvars, params);
</script>
```

The part that is throwing me off is ...

```
var params = {movie: "../video/puppy.flv"};
    swfobject.embedSWF("flash/osplayer.swf", "snow", "400", "320", "8.0.0", flashvars, params);
```

I understand the var params is suppose to be file location and the emded source is the osplayer but i dont have access to that player so i downloaded something called acg player that is able to play flv videos, (tested it and it works) but not sure how and where to place that information in the html code or if the file location i have to put in as to be like C:\Users...ect. , i've looked at videos and done some research and it seems the way its done is completely different.

someone please give me some advice on this or if im just not understanding or dumb

Comment: also i've downloaded adobe cs3 professional

Comment: Flash is no longer required to play animation in HTML, so you are probably better off not worrying about it at this point. Pick up a good book on HTML5/CSS3 that covers [animations](https://cloudinary.com/blog/creating_html5_animations) instead.

Comment: thanks for the advice and help

Comment: @ConnorBoyd why FLV instead of MP4? FLV and MP4 are video formats. MP4 can be auto-played by most browsers (when you use the `<video>` tag). SWF is an application format (sometimes app made to play videos, or games, or show texts). Just use the `<embed>` tag for MP4 video and you'll be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Better to skip this part of the tutorial, no more Flash is being used today anyway

[Google Chrome: Flash Usage Declines from 80% in 2014 to Under 8% Today](https://archive.is/ZVmJ8)

and also

> Adobe announces 2020 end-of-life for Flash

[Adobe flash update](https://theblog.adobe.com/adobe-flash-update/)